# Create dynamic months columns with sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union, pivot-table, dynamic-sql

I've already made a query that groups our account and sums of the revenue for each month. I basically want to create a temporary table with buckets for each month and add the revenue into that month if that records exists because this query only returns records for each month.

```
SELECT 
    p.New_AccountId AS AccountId,
    Account.Name AS AccountName,
    SUM(pf.New_Revenue) AS ForecastRevenue,
    pf.New_ForecastDate AS ForecastDate
FROM 
    ProfitRecoveryPartnersLLC_MSCRM.dbo.New_projectforecast AS pf 
INNER JOIN
    ProfitRecoveryPartnersLLC_MSCRM.dbo.New_project AS p ON p.New_projectId = pf.New_ProjectId 
INNER JOIN
    ProfitRecoveryPartnersLLC_MSCRM.dbo.Account ON pf.New_AccountId = Account.AccountId 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         Account.AccountId, SUM(pf.New_Revenue) AS ForecastMonthsRevenue
     FROM 
         ProfitRecoveryPartnersLLC_MSCRM.dbo.New_project AS p 
     INNER JOIN
         ProfitRecoveryPartnersLLC_MSCRM.dbo.New_projectforecast AS pf ON p.New_projectId = pf.New_ProjectId 
     INNER JOIN
         ProfitRecoveryPartnersLLC_MSCRM.dbo.Account ON pf.New_AccountId = Account.AccountId 
     WHERE 
         pf.statuscode = 1 GROUP BY AccountId) AS ForecastMonths ON ForecastMonths.AccountId = pf.New_AccountId
WHERE 
    pf.statuscode = 1
GROUP BY 
    p.New_AccountId, Account.Name, pf.New_ForecastDate
ORDER BY 
    Account.Name
```

[image]

> Generic Table Schema
>   AccountId - uniqueidentifier
>   Revenue - int
>   ForecastDate - DateTime

Is this possible to build. I'd like to avoid multiple set UNION statements that pull revenue for each month. Is there a way to dynamically create months between the first month(today's month) and the end of the last month that we have in our DB?

[image: Need to mimick something like this using sql]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    p.New_AccountId AS AccountId,
    Account.Name AS AccountName,
    SUM(pf.New_Revenue) AS ForecastRevenue,
    cast(Datepart(mm,pf.New_ForecastDate) as varchar) + '-' + cast(Datepart(YYYY,pf.New_ForecastDate) as varchar) as MonthYear
    into #temp
FROM 
    ProfitRecoveryPartnersLLC_MSCRM.dbo.New_projectforecast AS pf 
INNER JOIN
    ProfitRecoveryPartnersLLC_MSCRM.dbo.New_project AS p ON p.New_projectId = pf.New_ProjectId 
INNER JOIN
    ProfitRecoveryPartnersLLC_MSCRM.dbo.Account ON pf.New_AccountId = Account.AccountId 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         Account.AccountId, SUM(pf.New_Revenue) AS ForecastMonthsRevenue
     FROM 
         ProfitRecoveryPartnersLLC_MSCRM.dbo.New_project AS p 
     INNER JOIN
         ProfitRecoveryPartnersLLC_MSCRM.dbo.New_projectforecast AS pf ON p.New_projectId = pf.New_ProjectId 
     INNER JOIN
         ProfitRecoveryPartnersLLC_MSCRM.dbo.Account ON pf.New_AccountId = Account.AccountId 
     WHERE 
         pf.statuscode = 1 GROUP BY AccountId) AS ForecastMonths ON ForecastMonths.AccountId = pf.New_AccountId
WHERE 
    pf.statuscode = 1
GROUP BY 
    p.New_AccountId, Account.Name, pf.New_ForecastDate
ORDER BY 
    Account.Name

------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(MonthYear)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MonthYear FROM #temp) AS Courses

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT *
    FROM
  (SELECT AccountId, AccountName, MonthYear, ForecastRevenue
    FROM #temp) AS Sales
  PIVOT(SUM(BookSales)  
          FOR MonthYear IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```